# ImportError in Django REST Framework Tutorial 1: Serialization

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm working in a virtual env using Django 1.8 and Python 2.7. I installed REST framework and created a new project and just finished editing the snippets/models.py file by following the tutorial. When I go to create an initial migration of the snippet model using the command:

```
python manage.py makemigrations snippets
```

I get the error:

```
ImportError: No module named apps
```

My setting.py file INSTALLED_APPS is as follows:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'rest_framework',
'snippets.apps.SnippetsConfig',
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are a beginner don't use Django rest until you get enough comfort in using the Django first. Until then you can use JSONResponse with a function based view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `snippets` is the app you created. Then try this,

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'rest_framework',
'snippets',
)
```

If you are trying to create a **pluggable-django app**, please reffere this [Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/applications/#for-application-authors), because you are tried something like this

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks! I'm not sure why the tutorial recommends: INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'rest_framework',
    'snippets.apps.SnippetsConfig',
)

Comment: Glad to know that! Anyway I updated answer little bit with a reference which may be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to write down the app name correctly in install_apps, replace your setting with below.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
   'django.contrib.admin',
   'django.contrib.auth',
   'django.contrib.contenttypes',
   'django.contrib.sessions',
   'django.contrib.messages',
   'django.contrib.staticfiles',
   'rest_framework',
   'snippets',
)
```

Comment: why duplicate answers ?

Comment: We post at same time, less margin time

Answer (score 0):

Given the folder structure:

```
tutorial(src)/
  __init__.py
  settings.py
  wsgi.py
  urls.py
  ...
  snippets(app)/
     __init__.py
     urls.py
     views.py
     ...
manage.py
```

`manage.py` cannot find the snippets app nested in tutorials folder. So, you have to point directly to it in `settings.py`. This is what works for me:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'rest_framework',
    'tutorial.snippets', #<--- Solution
]
```